# Rails 3 Routes with match and the :as option, not matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a match route with the as option specified:

```
match ':major(/node/:id)/:minor' => 'nodes#show', :constraints => {:major => /(measure|change|analysis|report|manage|)/}, :as => :minor_section
```

when i use it with:

```
minor_section_path('manage', @node.id.to_s, 'overview')
```

I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"nodes", :action=>"show", :major=>"manage", :id=>"4d23522bcae8ab0316000120", :minor=>"overview"}
```

any one got any thoughts it looks right to me

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broken regular expression: Get rid of the extra pipe (|) after "manage" in your constraint.